# C count number of datapoints %d\n vs %lf\n

Tags: c, windows, count, scanf

I have a C code, normally I work with R so I am not 100% sure if the interpretation is right.

Lets assume that the input are daily stock returns. What will then be the number of periods? If the returns are all in a column (without empty rows) will it return one? If there is an empty row between two series of returns, will it return two? why does it count one time with `%d\n` and one time with `%lf\n` ?

```
int i,n;
FILE* input;
input = fopen(name,"r");
if(input == NULL) return -1;
//Read number of data points
fscanf(input,"%d\n",&n);
//Read number of periods (value of s - most likely going to stay 1)
fscanf(input,"%lf\n",&periods);
//Read the initial point (rescaled)
for(i=0;i<6;i++){
    fscanf(input,"%lf\n",&init_point[i]);
}
//Read the data points
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    fscanf(input,"%lf\n",&data[i]);
}
fclose(input);
//return number of data points
return n;
```

As it is very important I wanted to double-check if i read it correctly. Thanks! Btw I am especially interested in the number of periods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a assumption based on the code.

The number of periods is read as a floating point number, a value of 0.5 to indicate every 1/2 hour or 1/2 minute etc. so the data points are taken 1/2 or 1/2 minute apart.

To conclude, the data points are read as integer and each point interval is specified by the number of periods which might be float.